# Find out whether the data is present or not and segregate them using a C# code

Tags: c#

I'm writing a code to figure out the missing data and where i am having a mismatch or where it is not present.

There are 3 scenarios.

1. Images present as per db and in server (positive)
2. Images present in DB but not in Server.(Negative)
3. Images present in server but not in DB (Negative)

I have written a code using else if and i am able to capture only two scenario

1. Positive
2. Negative

How do i classify the two negative scenarios
(ie)Images present in DB but not in Server(Negative) and Images present in server but not in DB (Negative) to this code

```
namespace DataTableColumnCommaSeperated
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        fileOperation();
      }
      private static void fileOperation()
      {
        try
        {                
        string main_directory = @"D:\DMSArchivalPhase1\";//src_directory location
          string[] lead_list = File.ReadAllLines(main_directory + @"list.txt");//first input
            string[] image_list = File.ReadAllLines(main_directory + @"image_list.txt");//image name as per DB
              foreach(string lead_id in lead_list)
              {
              Console.WriteLine(lead_id);
              string[] src_list = File.ReadAllLines(main_directory + @"src_list.txt");
              foreach (string src_dir in src_list)
               {
               string final_path = src_dir + lead_id;
               if (Directory.Exists(final_path))
               {
                var filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(final_path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(name => !name.EndsWith(".gz"));//images present as per server
                foreach (string path in filePaths)
                  {
                   FileInfo f = new FileInfo(path);
                   string strNewName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f.Name);
                   if (Array.Exists(image_list, element => element == strNewName))
                   {
                    Console.WriteLine("File exist");
                   }
                   else if (Array.Exists(image_list, element => element != strNewName))
                   {
                   Console.WriteLine(strNewName + "File name doesnot exist in DMS/Databse");
                   }                               
                  }
               }
               }
              }               
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that you want a function that takes something which describes an image (like a file name?) and returns 'true' if the file is in file storage *and* if there's a corresponding record in the database, otherwise false?

Comment: @ScottHannen: Yes correct. My code can do that returing true or false. what I  required is a sub classification for the false/negative scenario 1.  Images present in DB but not in Server.(Negative) and Images present in server but not in DB (Negative)